# MongoDB: Get keys and values as separate arrays with new keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have the following MongoDB collection.

```
{
    "timestamp": "10:05:12",
    "value": 100
},
{
    "timestamp": "15:07:01",
    "value": 120
}, ...
```

Note: Here "..." implies more data with the same structure.

**Expected Result**

```
{
    "timestamps" : ["10:05:12", "15:07:01", ...],
    "values": [100, 120, ...]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by `null` and with `$push` to add `timestamp` and `value` into `timestamps` and `values` arrays respectively.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      timestamps: {
        $push: "$timestamp"
      },
      values: {
        $push: "$value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Km9v07QjEL2)